# find free ip address from ip range with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

table1 ip_pool - from 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.254

table2 users - user1 ip_address 10.0.0.2, user2 ip_address 10.0.0.3

how to find the next free ip example 10.0.0.4

tried this code but it show me all IP

```
function ip_range($start, $end)
{
$start = ip2long($start);
$end = ip2long($end); 
return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end) );
}

$range_one = "10.0.0.2";
$range_two = "10.0.0.254";
print_r( ip_range($range_one, $range_two) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this SQL does what you want:

```
select p.*
from ip_pool p
where p.ip_address not in (select u.ip_address from users u)
order by p.id_address
limit 1;
```